# Does S has to be transitive?

Tags: relations

Let R,S be relations over A when R is a partially ordered set, S is a s symmetrical relation $R \subset S$. Does S has to be transitive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything to answer this question on your own? (The -1 is from me.) Also, I guess you mean that $A$ is partially ordered by $R$.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Thank you I appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

$A=\{0,1,2\}$, $R=\emptyset$, $S=\{(0,1),(1,0), (1,2), (2,1)\}$ seems to me to be a counterexample.